# ionic actionsheet won't hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When i tap delete the action sheet sheet doesnt hide after a successful delete. Is there a way I could call the cancel from the deletePicture function?

```
$scope.deletePicture = function(post_id, pic_id, index){
     PostService.DeletePic(post_id, pic_id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
      .success(function (data) {
     $scope.pics.splice(index);
     hideSheet(); //doesn't Hide the action sheet
              }).
            error(function(error,status) {
          })   
    } 
$scope.update_or_delete = function(post_id,pic_id,index){

 $ionicActionSheet.show({
      titleText: 'Edit Photo',
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Change' },      
      ],
      destructiveText: 'Delete',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      cancel: function() {
        console.log('CANCELLED');
      },
      destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
                  $scope.deletePicture(post_id,pic_id,index);
                },

      buttonClicked: function(index) {
       if(index === 0){ // Camera BUtton
         $scope.changePicture();
       }
        return true;
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You must return true from the `destructiveButtonClicked` callback in order to automatically close the action sheet.

From the Docs :

> **destructiveButtonClicked** : Called when the destructive
>   button is clicked. **Return true to close the action sheet,** or false to
>   keep it opened.

So in your case, it will be :

```
  $ionicActionSheet.show({
      titleText: 'Edit Photo',
      buttons: [{
          text: 'Change'
      }, ],
      destructiveText: 'Delete',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      cancel: function() {
          console.log('CANCELLED');
      },
      destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
          $scope.deletePicture(post_id, pic_id, index);
          return true;
      },

      buttonClicked: function(index) {
          if (index === 0) { // Camera BUtton
              $scope.changePicture();
          }
          return true;
      }
  });
```

You can check out a demo [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/60fed1fbeb8d)